# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 connect to Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, odbc, ssms

Whenever I try to connect to my SQL server on Azure, I keep getting SQL error 258.

`Cannot connect to tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433.`

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

I setup and ODBC connection and that seemed to help it establish a connection but I am perplexed to why it is not connecting. I also have my IP address listed in Azure as an allowed IP Address, but still no luck. Here is what I am trying to log in with using SSMS 2012:

`Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Login: username@xxxxxxxxxx
Password: xxxxxxxxxx`

Connect to database: xxxxxxx_db
Connection time-out: 30
Encrypt: True

My Connection String:

`Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=database_db;User ID=username@xxxxxxxxxx;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;`

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you attempted to connect with ODBC using SQL Management Studio? You shouldn't have to use ODBC at all. Just connect to your SQL Azure server using your Admin credentials w/ the same connection dialog you would use for a local SQL server. Just don't try and specify the port with a :1433, just input the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Your Connection string seems to vary from what is shown here http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

Comment: I added my string in the question section but I don't see any differences other than the port number at the end of the server. Anyways, I tried it again just to be sure and still nothing. Thank you for the help, but any other ideas?

Comment: Well, your string includes the port and a timeout value. You could attempt to increase the timeout value, or omit it. Other than that, I am not sure. I think 1433 is the only port that Azure uses (but not positive). Therefore, specifying it is redundant.